# A Grid slowing the moving element on JS canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I'm drawing a grid on a JavaScript canvas on this canvas I also have a moving element so the Grid can be on/off with a button all is well apart from the speed of the moving element when grid is on it becomes extremely slow. I'm not really sure where am I going wrong. Can someone please give me some help. Thank you

HTML

```
<div>
    <input type=button id="up" onClick=move_img(id); value='Up'>
    <input type=button id="down"  onClick=move_img(id); value='Down'>
    <input type=button id="left"  onClick=move_img(id); value='Left'>
    <input type=button id="right"  onClick=move_img(id); value='Right'>
    <input type=button id="stop"  onClick=move_img(id); value='Stop'>
    <input type=button id="grid"  onClick=gridOn(); value='Grid'>
    <br>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    var isGrid = new Boolean(false);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    b = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var width = canvas.width = 600;
    var height = canvas.height = 400;
    
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    b.fillStyle = "#F0F8FF";
    b.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var posX = 10;
    posY = 10;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    
    setInterval(function () {
   
        b.fillStyle = "#F0F8FF";
        b.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        posX += x;
        posY += y;

        if (posX > width - 20) {
            x = 0;
            posX = width - 20;
        }
        if (posX < 0) {
            x = 0;
            posX = 0;
        }
        if (posY > height - 20) {
            y = 0;
            posY = height - 20;
        }
        if (posY < 0) {
            y = 0;
            posY = 0;
        }

    b.fillStyle = "red";
    b.fillRect(posX, posY, 20, 20);
    
    /**  Grid ***/
    if(isGrid){
        drawGrid();
    }
    /**************/
    
    }, 5)
   
    function move_img(id) {
        switch (id) {
        case "down":
            moveDown();
            break;
        case "up":
            moveUp();
            break;
        case "left":
            moveLeft();
            break;
        case "right":
            moveRight();
            break;
        case "stop":
            moveStop();
            break;
        }
    } 
    
    function moveDown(){
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
    }
    function moveUp(){
        x = 0;
        y = -1;
    }
    function moveLeft(){
        x = -1;
        y = 0;
    }
    function moveRight(){
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
    }
    function moveStop(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    function gridOn() {
        if(isGrid){
            isGrid = false;
        }else{
            isGrid = true;
        }
    } 
    
    function drawGrid(){    
        b.strokeStyle = 'black';
        b.lineWidth = 0.5;
        
        for(i = 0; i<= 600; i=i+40){
            b.moveTo(i, 0);
            b.lineTo(i, 600);
            b.stroke();
        }
        for(j = 0; j<= 600; j=j+40){
            b.moveTo(0, j);
            b.lineTo(600, j);
            b.stroke();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Both your loops in `drawGrid` are the same. If you want to reduce the "lagg" you could just move the contents of both loops into a single one. Also do you really need to draw every 5ms? That is +- 200 frames per second, try changing it to 1000/60 which is around 60 FPS

Comment: On the top of what Reyno's advices, one reason is too short interval, intervals tend to cumulate if there's not enough time to execute all the script. Take a look at [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), also you could consider to move the grid into its own canvas, which you need to draw only once, and swap the visibility only. To make the "player" faster, you can move it more than a single pixel at the time when using lower frame rate.

Comment: Thank you Reyno much better now. Teemu working on your idea too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 `canvas` with `position absolute`. One for red box and another for `Grid`. That will help you to move box without clearing grid.

Also, you can follow @reyno's advice that will help you to reduce some loops.

Also, you can make only one method `move` and use it for all sides by passing `x` and `y` based on button. This will reduce the line of code.

See the Snippet below:

```js
var isGrid = new Boolean(false);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    b = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    var gridCanvas = document.getElementById("grid-canvas");
    bGrid = gridCanvas.getContext("2d");

    var width = gridCanvas.width = 600;
    var height = gridCanvas.height = 400;
    
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    
    //document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    bGrid.fillStyle = "#F0F8FF";
    bGrid.fillRect(0, 0, gridCanvas.width, gridCanvas.height);
    b.fillRect(0, 0, gridCanvas.width, gridCanvas.height);

    var posX = 10;
    posY = 10;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    let _interval = null;
    drawImg();
    
    if(isGrid){
        drawGrid();
    }
    
    function drawImg(){
      _interval = setInterval(function(){
         /*b.fillStyle = "#F0F8FF";
          b.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);*/
          b.clearRect(0,0, width, height);
          posX += x;
          posY += y;

          if (posX > width - 20) {
              x = 0;
              posX = width - 20;
          }
          if (posX < 0) {
              x = 0;
              posX = 0;
          }
          if (posY > height - 20) {
              y = 0;
              posY = height - 20;
          }
          if (posY < 0) {
              y = 0;
              posY = 0;
          }

          b.fillStyle = "red";
          b.fillRect(posX, posY, 20, 20);
      }, 1000/60)
    }
    
    function stopImg(){
        clearInterval(_interval);
    }
   
    function move_img(id) {
        switch (id) {
        case "down":
            move(0,1);
            break;
        case "up":
            move(0,-1);
            break;
        case "left":
            move(-1,0);
            break;
        case "right":
            move(1,0);
            break;
        case "stop":
            move(0,0);
            break;
        }
    } 
    
    function move(_x,_y){
        x = _x;
      y = _y;
      if(_x ==0 && _y==0){
        stopImg();
      }else{
        drawImg();
      }
    }
    
    /*function moveDown(){
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
    }
    function moveUp(){
        x = 0;
        y = -1;
    }
    function moveLeft(){
        x = -1;
        y = 0;
    }
    function moveRight(){
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
    }
    function moveStop(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }*/
    function gridOn() {
        if(isGrid){
            isGrid = false;
            bGrid.clearRect(0,0, width, height);
            bGrid.fillRect(0,0, width, height);
        }else{
            isGrid = true;
            bGrid.fillRect(0,0, width, height);
            drawGrid();
        }
    } 
    
    function drawGrid(){ 
        bGrid.strokeStyle = 'black';
        bGrid.lineWidth = 0.5;
        
        for(i = 0; i<= 600; i=i+40){
            bGrid.moveTo(i, 0);
            bGrid.lineTo(i, 600);
            bGrid.stroke();
            
            bGrid.moveTo(0, i);
            bGrid.lineTo(600, i);
            bGrid.stroke();
        }
       /* for(j = 0; j<= 600; j=j+40){
            b.moveTo(0, j);
            b.lineTo(600, j);
            b.stroke();
        }*/
    }
```

```css
canvas{
  position: absolute;
}

#canvas{
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type=button id="up" onClick=move_img(id); value='Up'>
    <input type=button id="down"  onClick=move_img(id); value='Down'>
    <input type=button id="left"  onClick=move_img(id); value='Left'>
    <input type=button id="right"  onClick=move_img(id); value='Right'>
    <input type=button id="stop"  onClick=move_img(id); value='Stop'>
    <input type=button id="grid"  onClick=gridOn(); value='Grid'>
    <br>
    <p></p>
</div>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="grid-canvas"></canvas>
```

You can also test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/4ru3z50q/)